# Finding the highest, lowest, total, average and median from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, arrays, boxplot

I am creating a boxplot generator in Ruby, and I need to calculate some things.

Let's say I have this array:

```
arr = [1, 5, 7, 2, 53, 65, 24]
```

How can I find the lowest value (1), highest value (65), total (157), average (22.43) and median (7) from the above array?

Thanks

Comment: would recommend changing the line total = arr.inject(:+)
to total = arr.inject(0, :+) to avoid getting a nil value

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
lowest = arr.min
highest = arr.max
total = arr.inject(:+)
len = arr.length
average = total.to_f / len # to_f so we don't get an integer result
sorted = arr.sort
median = len % 2 == 1 ? sorted[len/2] : (sorted[len/2 - 1] + sorted[len/2]).to_f / 2
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more careful with the median, in case `arr.length` is divisible by 2.  A method that should always work is `do sortedarr = arr.sort ; medpt1 = arr.length / 2 ; medpt2 = (arr.length+1)/2 ; (sortedarr[medpt1] + sortedarr[medpt2]).to_f / 2 ; end`, but obviously that's more expensive, and not as nice and pretty, as what you have in your answer.

Comment: One minor note: arr.inject(:+) will only work in Ruby 1.8.7 or greater (or if another library has implemented Symbol#to_proc, as Rails' ActiveSupport does).  Otherwise, arr.inject {|sum, n| sum + n} would work.

Comment: @GregCampbell: `arr.inject(:+)` does not invoke `Symbol#to_proc`, inject invokes `rb_funcall` directly when given a symbol (which is a lot faster than passing a block (or worse using Symbol#to_proc)). But you're right that it only works in 1.8.7+.

Comment: Since you're sorting the array to find the median, would it be more efficient overall to find the minimum and maximum with sorted.first and sorted.last?

Comment: @DavidAldridge in absolute terms yes, however the time complexity of the sorting is O(nlogn) and will eat up the O(n) of the min and max operations anyway for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the minimum, maximum, sum and average are trivial and can be done easily in linear time as shown by sepp2k's answer above.

Finding the *median* is less trivial and the naive implementation (sorting, and then taking the middle element) runs in O(nlogn) time.

There are, however, algorithms that find the median in linear time (such as the median-of-5 algorithm). Others work even for any kind of order statistic (say, you want to find the 5th-smallest element). The problem with those is that you would have to implement them yourself,  I know of no Ruby implementation.

O(nlogn) is quite fast already, so if you're not planning on working on huge datasets (and if you will need to sort your data anyway), you'll be fine with that.